# Getting Static from NonStatic Java (ActionListener)

Tags: java, swing, static, actionlistener

From my action listener which I believe is static, im trying to call a non static method from a class. How can i call my method from my class?

```
public class addContent {

    User Darryl = new User();
    public static void addStuff(){

        //Panel and Frame
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PandaHunterV3");
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Setup labels
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        //Setup buttons
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        //Action listener
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                Darryl.showHealth();    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM. 
            }
        });

        //Crap
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);   
    }
}
```

and my class from which i am trying to call the methods from

```
public class User {

    int health;

    User(){
        health = 50;
    }

    public void showHealth(){        
        System.out.print(health);
    }

    public void incHealth(){
        health += 20;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Your code is very hard to read because you don't follow the java naming conventions.

Comment: Your ActionListener is an anonymous inner class. Nothing static about it, and nothing to do with your title either. You don't seem to have understood the error message you got, let alone transcribed it correctly. The only issue here is that you're trying to call a non-static method via a class name, and you can't do that: you need an instance. Not a real question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:
Mark the `Daryl` instance as static or the method `addStuff()` as non-static.

btw. use low case for naming the variables / instances and upper-case for class names.

```
public class AddContent {
    private User darryl = new User();

    public void addStuff(){

        //Panel and Frame
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PandaHunterV3");
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Setup labels
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        //Setup buttons
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        //Action listener
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                AddContent.this.darryl.showHealth();    // SHOULD BE FINE
            }
        });
        //Crap
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


}

}
```

Comment: Final has not changed my error. Thanks for the tip on the variables.

Comment: Fixed by moving instance into my addStuff method. Thanks!

Comment: Basically, from anonymous classes (`new ActionListener(){}` is an anonymous class) you can access only final variables from the outer scope or class' variables (static or non-static). But at the same time you can't access non-static variable from a static context.